# I want to bind event with div width change?

Tags: jquery

I want to  perform some action on change the width of div . Div width is auto . when the user change the zoom of screen. The Div width is automatically change . then i want to perform some action .

Comment: What do you mean by "change the zoom of change"? Do you want to track when the user resizes the browser window or when browser zooming is used?

Comment: yes altschuler i want this type of event to bind with div

Comment: Which one? :-) 

You can use .resize() to track when things change size: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: thank altschuler i need this type of event

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any official zoom event that you can register to, but there are some hack implementations that may or may not work

( i tested with latest version of all browsers )

- I found this one to be working in FF and chrome except IE
  http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fontresizing/
- This approach uses flash and seems to be working in IE , FF and
  chrome http://novemberborn.net/2007/12/javascriptpage-zoom-ff3-128

I found these after a quick google search, there might be more or better approaches, but these should give you a head start.

Comment: thank for reply helmus. i found my solution with resize event

Comment: @pargan that event does seem to handle zooming as well, good find.